# What does "The search is over" means in Grails?

Tags: grails

Does anybody knows what is "The search is over" means? I tried to find out but nowhere it has been mentioned.

Note: I am preparing a presentation on Grails for that I wants to understand this term.
Thanks.

Comment: May I know why downvote?

Comment: I'm not responsible for the downvote, but I would assume it is because this isn't really a question that is appropriate for Stack Overflow. SO is more for questions regarding programming issues and less of a discussion forum for questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you don't have to keep looking for a better Java/Groovy framework, because grails is the ultimatum (or so it claims). And you have found the 'holy grails' that unlock the mystic power of web app development on JVM. The ultimate truth. :P